# Efficiency in maping AWS API Gateway GetUsageResponse to add API name and Dates

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-api-gateway

I am working on allowing my Java Spring Boot Lambda application to call the ApiGatewayClient in order to getUsage information for my various API keys. The problem is that the data comes back without the API key name *and* without the queried dates. I have crafted a solution that works, but it is quite verbose and I am sure there is a more efficient and elegant way to achieve the same task.

example API call:  `myapi/getUsage?startDate=2023-03-31&endDate=2023-04-04`

So, I am trying to turn the following response:

```
{
  "1barly5j0m": [
    [16664, 0],
    [281, 0],
    [209, 0],
    [16448, 0],
    [15004, 0]
  ],
  "2foo8fk3jb": [
    [52, 0],
    [301, 0],
    [262, 0],
    [190, 0],
    [349, 0]
  ],
  "3bar9utjr1": [
    [1773, 0],
    [14779, 0],
    [13994, 0],
    [12448, 0],
    [14208, 0]
  ]
}
```

Into a JSON responseEntity like this:

```
{
  "Agents": {
    "usage": {
      "2023-03-31": "16664",
      "2023-04-01": "281",
      "2023-04-02": "209",
      "2023-04-03": "16448",
      "2023-04-04": "15004"
    },
    "id": "1barly5j0m"
  },
  "Supervisors": {
    "usage": {
      "2023-03-31": "52",
      "2023-04-01": "301",
      "2023-04-02": "262",
      "2023-04-03": "190",
      "2023-04-04": "349"
    },
    "id": "2foo8fk3jb"
  },
  "Customers": {
    "usage": {
      "2023-03-31": "1773",
      "2023-04-01": "14779",
      "2023-04-02": "13994",
      "2023-04-03": "12448",
      "2023-04-04": "14208"
    },
    "id": "3bar9utjr1"
  }
}
```

**Requirements:**

1. Map the Key ID to proper Key Name
2. Map usage value to date (we are not using quotas so only the first number matters)
3. Dates must be sorted (I know, I know, JSON is an unordered collection, but they **can** be ordered!)

---

### Current Implementation

```
package com.contactAPI.service;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.deplayer.aws.ApiGatewayConfig;

import software.amazon.awssdk.services.apigateway.ApiGatewayClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.apigateway.model.BadRequestException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.apigateway.model.GetUsageRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.apigateway.model.GetUsageResponse;

@Service
public class AWSService {

    private ApiGatewayClient apiGateway;

    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllUsage(String startDate, String endDate) {
        ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity;
        apiGateway = ApiGatewayConfig.getApiGatewayClient();
        JSONObject outputObj = new JSONObject();
        GetUsageRequest request = GetUsageRequest.builder()
                .usagePlanId("myplanid")
                .startDate(startDate)
                .endDate(endDate)
                .build();
        try {
            GetUsageResponse response = apiGateway.getUsage(request);
            if (!response.items().isEmpty()) {
                outputObj = outputBuilder(response, startDate);
                responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(outputObj.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
        } catch (BadRequestException ex) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }

    private JSONObject outputBuilder(GetUsageResponse response, String startDate) 
            throws JSONException {
        JSONObject outputObj = new JSONObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<List<Long>>> entry : response.items().entrySet()) {
            JSONObject tempObj = new JSONObject();
            switch (entry.getKey()) {
            case "1barly5j0m":
                tempObj.put("id", "1barly5j0m");
                tempObj.put("usage", getDateValues(entry.getValue(), startDate));
                outputObj.put("Agents", tempObj);
            break;
            case "2foo8fk3jb":
                tempObj.put("id", "2foo8fk3jb");
                tempObj.put("usage", getDateValues(entry.getValue(), startDate));
                outputObj.put("Supervisors", tempObj);
            break;
            case "3bar9utjr1":
                tempObj.put("id", "3bar9utjr1");
                tempObj.put("usage", getDateValues(entry.getValue(), startDate));
                outputObj.put("Customers", tempObj);
            break;
            }
        }
        return outputObj;
    }

    private JSONObject getDateValues(List<List<Long>> list, String startDate) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> dateMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        int count = 0;
        for (List<Long> arr : list) {
            String usageValue = arr.get(0).toString();
            String newDate = LocalDate.parse(startDate).plusDays(count).toString();
            dateMap.put(newDate, usageValue);
            count++;
        }
        JSONObject orderedJson = new JSONObject(dateMap);
        return orderedJson;
    }

}
```

---

### QUESTION

The big issue that I see is that I have 10 API keys, so it feels like the hard coded switch case is a bit much. Is there a better way to do that?

Should I be using while(Iterator.hasNext()) instead of the for-each loop with count variable?

Any other improvements you can see?

---

**NOTE:**
For ordered org.json.JSONObject, version 20080701 has a constructor that uses the type of Map you give it rather than later implementations that only use HashMap. So in this case, I am providing a LinkedHashMap, and so "orderedJson" maintains the insertion order when creating the JSONObject.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20080701</version>
        </dependency>
```